# How to make a tiff z-stack conserving or adding metadata?

Tags: python, tiff

I have a number of tiff files that I would like to combine to a z-stack using python. The individual files have metadata that I would like to conserve ([OME](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/ome-model/ome-tiff/) in my case), in particular the information on which z slice it is. Alternatively, I would like to insert somewhere in the z-stack's metadata that it is a z-stack (and not e.g. a time-lapse. I need this for opening the stacks correctly with Bioformats in ImageJ).

I can make a z-stack using e.g. [tifffile.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html), reading the individual files like in this simple example:

```
img1 = tifffile.imread(path_to_img1)
img2 = tifffile.imread(path_to_img2)
zstack = np.zeros((2, img1.shape[0], img1.shape[1]))
zstack[0] = img1
zstack[1] = img2
tifffile.imsave(path, zstack)
```

and I can also read the individual metadata information using `tifffile.TiffFile`.

However, I cannot see how to attach metadata for each slice. Tifffile has an option to add extra tags (including tag ID 270, the image description), but I don't understand how to apply this to each individual slice. On the other hand, the tifffile.TiffFile object has no write method.

I am not limited to tifffile and have also tried to use PIL, but have not succeeded.

Comment: Use the `tifffile.TiffWriter`class rather than the `imsave` function to incrementally add images to the file. Consider HDF5 (via [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html)) instead of custom TIFF for storing large amounts of image and meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import bioformats.omexml as ome
import tifffile
import sys
            
def writeplanes(pixel, SizeT=1, SizeZ=1, SizeC=1, order='TZCYX', verbose=False):

    if order == 'TZCYX':

        p.DimensionOrder = ome.DO_XYCZT
        counter = 0
        for t in range(SizeT):
            for z in range(SizeZ):
                for c in range(SizeC):

                    if verbose:
                        print('Write PlaneTable: ', t, z, c),
                        sys.stdout.flush()

                    pixel.Plane(counter).TheT = t
                    pixel.Plane(counter).TheZ = z
                    pixel.Plane(counter).TheC = c
                    counter = counter + 1

    return pixel


# Dimension TZCXY
SizeT = 1
SizeZ = n_zs
SizeC = n_chs
SizeX = 2048
SizeY = 2048
Series = 0


scalex = 0.1
scaley = scalex
scalez = 0.5
pixeltype = 'uint16'
dimorder = 'TZCYX'
output_file = os.path.join(out_dir, 'R{}'.format(i), file)

# create numpy array with correct order
img5d = np.random.randn(SizeT, SizeZ, SizeC, SizeY, SizeX).astype(np.uint16)

# Getting metadata info
omexml = ome.OMEXML()
omexml.image(Series).Name = output_file
p = omexml.image(Series).Pixels
#p.ID = 0
p.SizeX = SizeX
p.SizeY = SizeY
p.SizeC = SizeC
p.SizeT = SizeT
p.SizeZ = SizeZ
p.PhysicalSizeX = np.float(scalex)
p.PhysicalSizeY = np.float(scaley)
p.PhysicalSizeZ = np.float(scalez)
p.PixelType = pixeltype
p.channel_count = SizeC
p.plane_count = SizeZ * SizeT * SizeC
p = writeplanes(p, SizeT=SizeT, SizeZ=SizeZ, SizeC=SizeC, order=dimorder)

for c in range(SizeC):
    if pixeltype == 'unit8':
        p.Channel(c).SamplesPerPixel = 1
    if pixeltype == 'unit16':
        p.Channel(c).SamplesPerPixel = 2


omexml.structured_annotations.add_original_metadata(ome.OM_SAMPLES_PER_PIXEL, str(SizeC))

# Converting to omexml
xml = omexml.to_xml()

# write file and save OME-XML as description
tifffile.imwrite(output_file, img5d, metadata={'axes': dimorder}, description=xml)
```