# Generate Z-Stack of images and create a 2D top-down view of the stacked image using python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have n number of images with same size that need to be stacked along Z-Axis as shown in figure creating a sort of 3D Model. I have tried doing this using Z-Stack with different libraries (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978698/how-to-make-a-tiff-z-stack-conserving-or-adding-metadata)) then I need to create a top down view with of stacked images converting the 3D model into 2D image.

I have tried rotating each slice and making a TIFF-Z Stack out of it, but can not seem to make it work.[image]

Total number of n Images (ABCD), each with size of H x W pixels would be stacked along Z-Axis like in figure creating a top down view ABFE with a size of W x n pixels.

ABFE is what i intend to achieve.

Since I am new to image processing, any help (also which terms to research after) would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every image in OpenCV is 3-dimensional tensor, the last dimension being number of channels, 3 usually. Stacking them along another new dimension requires a 4-dimensional tensor.

```
W, H, n = 300, 200, 5
num_channels = 3 
# shape is (height, width, channels)
im = np.zeros((H, W, num_channels), dtype=np.uint8) # analogue of cv2.imread('test1.jpg')                                                                                                
images = [np.zeros_like(im) for i in range(5)]
# here goes the interesting part
meta_image = np.stack(images)
print(meta_image.shape) # (5, 200, 300, 3) == (n, H, W, num_channels)

# the top most image can be accessed as a slice
top_img = meta_image[:, 0, ...]
cv2.imshow("top", top_img)
# the bottom one
bottom_img = meta_image[:, H-1, ...]
cv2.imshow("bottom", bottom_img)
print(top_img.shape) # (5, 300, 3) == (n, W, num_channels)

# in case you want something like mean over this H slices:
some_mean_slice = np.mean(meta_image, axis=1).astype(np.uint8)
print(some_mean_slice.shape) # (5, 300, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is heading in the direction I want. Is there any way to merge all Slices to create a 2D image stacked on top of each other so i just have a 2D image rather than each slice?

Comment: Updated my code to include mean slice, in case that is what you want

Comment: That is what I wanted. Is there any way to merge the slices instead of getting mean value, as the mean slice contains less pixels as compared to mean slices generated by other apps (e.g. ImageJ)? Thank you for your effort!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by merging? What shape should this merged image be? Could you show any examples?

Answer (score 0):

In numpy, you would use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```py
import numpy as np

# height, width, and z
x = 10
y = 5
z = 3

# create random 3-d array of shape (x,y,z) to represent images
img1 = np.random.rand(x,y,z)
img2 = np.random.rand(x,y,z)
img3 = np.random.rand(x,y,z)

img1.shape
>>> (10, 5, 3)

# concatenate along the z axis
out_img = np.concatenate([img1, img2, img3], axis=2)
out_img.shape
>>> (10, 5, 9)
```

The `axis` argument here is the key, it tells numpy what axis (aka which dimension) to concatenate the input list of arrays along. Dimensions start from 0, so the first dimesnions `axis=0` represents the x axis in this case, the second dimension `axis=1` is the y axis, and third dimension `axis=2` is the z axis.